# Required property in jsp page

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I'm using spring mvc and i look for a way to validate my form at client side, so i found this code of html 5.

```
<form:input path="login" type="text" required />
```

I put the required property in input element of my form in my jsp page but i got 500 http error.

```
Etat HTTP 500 - /WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp (line: 44, column: 48) Symbole égal (equal) attendu

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp (line: 44, column: 62) Symbole égal (equal) attendu
```

Comment: This `required` attribute can only be used in html5 tags, not in spring `form` tag.

Comment: so how can i change spring tag ?

Comment: You cannot use required property in spring tag. All you need to do is use some client side validation using (jQuery/JS)

Comment: Check this link [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use the required attribute, but with XHTML syntax instead of short HTML syntax:

```
<form:input required="" .../>
```

or

```
<form:input required="required" .../>
```

Comment: thanks it's work ;) but i have a little problem, for some test i don't use the input submit i go through ajax call to submit my form like this `if(responce) $('#formlogin').submit();` so after some handling the form is submit and the required option doesn't work.

Comment: Plz Check for IE Compability?

Comment: `required=""` didn't seem to work for me but `required="required"` did

Comment: best answer ever

Answer (score 1):

Validation using jQuery plugin is very simple and easy to use,
All you need to do is add `jquery.validate.js` file in your jsp 
and follow the code in script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formID").validate({
        rules : {
            login : {
                required : true                 
            }
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

And in yout html,

```
<form:form id="formID" >
   <form:input path="login" type="text" id="login" />
</form:form>
```

Hope this will be useful.

Comment: `login` in jquery function refer to `path` or `id` of `input` element ?

Comment: it doesn't work `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.27/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#formlogin").validate({
         rules : {
             login : {
                 required : true                 
             }
         },
     });
 });
 </script>` my form: `<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="auth" action="welcome" id="formlogin">
  <label>login</label>
  <form:input path="login"  type="text" id="login"  />`

Comment: Did you see any console errors? login refers to id of an input element.

Comment: There is no js file available in this path `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.27/jquery.form-validator.min.js`

Comment: Have you added `jquery.js` file in your jsp file? this should load before validation file.

Comment: of course i added it. i already try some jquery code and it's work.